# Extract negative integers from JSON

Tags: sql, json, presto, json-extract, trino

I am using the `json_extract` function in PrestoSQL, however, if the key-value pair appears with a negative integer in the value such as

```
{"foo":-12345, "bar": 12345}
```

`json_extract(json, '$.foo')` will return NULL but

`json_extract(json, '$.bar')` will return 12345

`json_extract_scalar` also produces the same.

What is the workaround for extracting negative integers in Presto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works as expected in current `master` (Presto 320):

```
presto:default> SELECT json_extract(JSON '{"foo":-12345, "bar": 12345}', '$.foo');
 _col0
--------
 -12345
(1 row)
```

```
presto:default> SELECT json_extract_scalar(JSON '{"foo":-12345, "bar": 12345}', '$.foo');
 _col0
--------
 -12345
(1 row)
```